# How to disable the router's WiFi while keeping Ethernet enabled?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, parental-controls

At my house, the kids all use WiFi, while the adults use Ethernet. I want to let the adults use the Internet at any hour, while denying access to the kids at 9:30 PM. I also want to keep them off in the morning until half an hour after wake-up time.

The adults are connected to the router via Ethernet (using 3 of the 4 slots on the router), and the 4th port is open so that we can connect a Blu-Ray player in a different room (this is meant to be annoying, because it shouldn't happen very often).

Is there a way to disable WiFi between 9:30 and the morning? I'd prefer an easily implemented and flexible software solution, rather than using a timer or some similar solution.

Using NetGear WGR614v7 Wireless Router and WinXPsp3.

Comment: Which router are you using. Depending on the model and the OS it is running it might be as simple as sending a single command to turn WiFi on or off. (Or even to add that command to cron).

Comment: If you open your browser, go to http://www.routerlogin.net and login using **admin** and **password** (or whatever you changed it to), then under [Advanced / Wireless Settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zkS6l.png) do you see an option to [Turn off wireless signal by schedule](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yCj33.png)?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WGR614V7/wgr614v7_ref_manual_20apr06.pdf), it seems that your best automated option would be to configure the ip addresses so that the children's are in a range that excludes those of the adults.  You can block a range of ip addresses on a schedule but it doesn't look like you can disable wifi by schedule.

Comment: This should work. However, if the kids are aware of the scheme employed they could circumvent it by specifying an IP address in their device.

Comment: You could lock in the last available ips for the adults and block all other ranges.

Answer (score 2):

This [will not work](http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/wgr614v7-and-tomato-firmware.26485/) on your router, but you might be interested to know that the Tomato custom firmware supports this functionality natively. If things don't end up working (eg. Eric Roper's suggestion), it might be worth investing in a [Tomato-supported router](http://tomatousb.org/doc:build-types).

On Tomato USB, the configuration page looks like this (I'm on an ASUS RT-N16 router):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Workaround:

One can schedule WiFi sleep/shutdown using `crontab`.

```
crontab -e 
00 07 * * * wl -i eth1 radio on
30 23 * * * wl -i eth1 radio off
```